# Imagick annotateImage: how to set text position from the top left

Tags: php, text, position, imagick

I'm trying to create a wrapper function around `annotateImage` to be able to set the exact top and left positions of a given text. The default method sets the y-position from the baseline, which means there has to be a lot of experimentation involved if one wants to draw a text at an exact spot on an image. This is what I mean...

```
$image->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, 'The quick brown fox');
```

In the above code, the text is invisible because the y position is 0. So to fix this, I've started with the following function where I add an offset of 40 to y...

```
function addText($image, $draw, $x, $y, $text) {
  $y = $y + 40;
  $image->annotateImage($draw, $x, $y, 0, $text);
}

addText($image, $draw, 0, 0, 'The quick brown fox'); // draw at 0, 0
```

But it's not very reliable because it doesn't take into account any factors such as font size, etc...

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You could try to use setPointSize to set a specific font size, or getFontSize to get the size and base your height on that. I haven't tried, but you may have to calculate points to pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution that works well. If the gravity is set to 'NorthWest', the text tends to keep its x y position from the top left.

```
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTHWEST);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, 'The quick brown fox');
```

Comment: Work as a charm!